# MVC Ajax update partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to update the partial view every time the ActionLink is clicked. I'm passing the same model to the partial view as the main view. The problem is that partial view is not getting updated. Not sure if I'm on right track.

**View** :

```
@model MyPoll.Models.Poll

@Ajax.ActionLink("For", "AddPositive", new RouteValueDictionary { {"id", Model.Id }},new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "countsDiv" })

<div id="countsDiv">
    @Html.Partial("Counts", Model)
</div>
```

**Partial**:

```
@model MyPoll.Models.Poll

Positive count : @Model.PositiveCount
Negative count : @Model.NegativeCount
```

**Controller action** :

```
public ActionResult AddPositive(int id)
{
    Poll poll = db.Polls.Find(id);
    poll.PositiveCount++;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View(poll);
}
```

The scripts are referenced as well:

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Are `MicrosoftAjax.js` and `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js` referenced? And jQuery too?

Comment: did you do the basic debugging: check if you have any js errors, if you see the request being made, if the controller action receives the requests, if the the data being returned is actually updated??

Comment: if the microsoft libs rely on the jquery library, you might need to reference the jquery library before the others

Comment: @Nadir MicrosoftMvcAjax and MicrosoftAjax don't depend on jQuery, but jquery.unobtrusive might ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed:

In action :

```
public **PartialViewResult** AddPositive(int id)
    {
        Poll poll = db.Polls.Find(id);
        poll.PositiveCount++;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return **PartialView**("Counts", poll);
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that's kind of lame. Any explanation on why we need the separation? Did you get any error messages? How'd you figure this out?

Comment: @vbullinger, I don't remember what error was that, but I had to return PartialView instead of View to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me too. The same error, but I could not figure out why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are loading jquery last.  The other js depends on jquery.